# redux-form : How to display form values on another component

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-form

I am using redux-form 6.0.0-rc.5 and I am trying to display the form values as they are entered by the user.

However, I want these values to be displayed from another component, not the redux form itself.

So, my simplified App architecture would be like that :

```
<App />              -> (main component -container ?-)
  <List />           -> (connect to form values and pass them down)
    <Elem />         -> (display form value)
  <Form />           -> (enter form values)
```

The  component is a redux-form mounted to 'form' and is working.

```
Form = reduxForm({
  form: 'formName'
})(Form)
```

**What would be a good way of getting the form values (from state form.formName.values) and send them to my Display component ?**

Things I have tried :

- Connect **App** to the store and *mapStateToProps* (form.formName.values) then pass it down to Display as a prop. But it throws an error since values does not exist in the form state until the user has typed anything.
- Using the function **getFormValues**('formName') provided by redux-form inside the List component but it returns a function or undefined :

**Elem**

```
const Elem = ({ name }) => (
  <li>{name}</li>
)
```

**List**

```
const List = ({ values }) => (
  {values.map(value => <Elem name={value.name} />)}      
)

List = connect(
  state => ({
    values: getFormValues('formName')
  })
)(List)
```

There must be something I am missing or I still do not understand correctly whether it is with redux-form or redux itself... I hope someone will be able to enlighten me !

Thank you and have a great day.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try using

```
List = connect(
  state => ({
    values: getFormValues(state.form.formName)
  })
)(List)
```

instead. At least that's how it worked in v5, although there the method was called `getValues` and not `getFormValues`.

Edit:
After a quick look at the docs it seems in v6 you'll have to use a `formValueSelector`: http://redux-form.com/6.0.0-rc.3/examples/selectingFormValues/

Comment: Yes. `formValueSelector` is the answer.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I saw the selecting form values example, however my understanding of the docs was the following : the getFormValues function is a quick way to get all values from a given form anywhere in the application (tab "Selectors" in the docs). And the formValueSelector was made to get specific values (meaning not necessarily all values) while in a redux-form in order to use them inside the form itself. Is that correct ? And if I need to use formValueSelector, do I then need to associate all my form fields to the selector ? Thank you again guys !

Comment: Edit : Allright, I made it work with formValueSelector but then I tried it again with getFormValues and this is the exact syntax that is now working for me :

`const  selector = getFormValues('fomName')

List = connect({ state => ({ values: selector(state) }) })(List)`

The other syntax in my original question was not working. Maybe it will help someone as well !

Comment: Do you think you could link your solution? I'm trying to do the same thing.

Comment: I'm Using this method but Can't find variable 'List' error occur. 

How to fix that ?

Answer (score 3):

[**`formValueSelector()`**](http://redux-form.com/6.4.1/docs/api/FormValueSelector.md/) is not necessary.

You also can directly access it as a property.

```
List = connect(
  state => ({
    formValues: {
       id: state.form.formName.values.id
    }
  })
)(List)
```

Same as

```
List = connect(
  state => ({
    formValues: {
       id: formValueSelector('formName')(state, 'id')
    }
  })
)(List)
```

Comment: do you know the same technique to update value from any form ?

Comment: https://redux-form.com/7.3.0/docs/api/actioncreators.md/   1. import reduxFormActions from 'redux-form/es/actions';    
2. bind the change action to your component with redux: bindActionCreators(reduxFormActions.change, dispatch)   
3. call action: this.props.actionsReduxForm('formName', fieldName, fieldValue)

Comment: bindActionCreators did not work, just this.props.dispatch(change('myform', fieldKey, filterValue));

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. Apparently, 'values' is a saved name in redux-form. Using [Iurii Budnikov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3590109/iurii-budnikov) advice I managed to solve the problem - just change the the variable name from 'values' to something else in your connect call:

```
List = connect(
  state => ({
    formValues: getFormValues(state.form.formName)
  })
)(List)
```

Answer (score 0):

Starting from redux-form `6.0.0` (and still the same in `7.0.0`), you can use the function `formValueSelector()` to select values from any redux form you have in your application: http://redux-form.com/7.0.0/docs/api/FormValueSelector.md/

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { formValueSelector } from 'redux-form';

const selector = formValueSelector('formName');

List = connect(
  state => ({
    name: selector(state, 'name')
  })
)(List)
```

Comment: I'm trying to create a preview component where all values are shown before user can submit the form. I'm trying to get all form values from a wizard form which is named "wizard". following this answer gives me "wizard is not defined" error. What should I do?