# redux form update state and retrieve

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, jsx, redux-form

I have 2 redux form components, first one is **LoginFormComponent** which is a redux-form with form name '**submitValidation**'

```jsx
LoginFormComponent = reduxForm({
  form: 'submitValidation'
})(LoginFormComponent)
```

This form component has input field like so:-

```jsx
<Field name="userid" size="22" placeholder="Personal ID" 
maxLength="22" component="input" type="text"/>
```

On form submit, I want to navigate to the second redux form component which is **VerifyLoginBodyComponent** and would like to show the submitted "userid" from the first component inside a div like so:-

```jsx
<div className="tieringElement">
       You are logging in as:&nbsp;&nbsp;<b>{userid}</b>
</div>
```

This is how I handle submit in the first form component

```jsx
    class LoginFormComponent extends Component {
            constructor(props){
                super(props);
                this.submit=this.submit.bind(this);
            }
            submit(values) {
                console.log(JSON.stringify(values));
                this.context.router.push('/verify');

            }
           render(){
             const { handleSubmit } = this.props
             return(
               <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(this.submit)} id="loginform">
                 <Field name="userid" size="22" placeholder="Personal ID" maxLength="22" component="input" type="text"/>
              </form>
            )
    }

LoginFormComponent = reduxForm({
  form: 'submitValidation'
})(LoginFormComponent)

export default LoginFormComponent;
```

This is my redux store:

```jsx
const INITIAL_APP_STATE = {
    form: {
        submitValidation: {
            userid: ''
        }
    }
};
```

How can I access the submitted userid from LoginFormComponent inside VerifyLoginBodyComponent?

I checked https://redux-form.com/6.5.0/examples/selectingFormValues/, [Redux-form handleSubmit: How to access store state?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37539601/redux-form-handlesubmit-how-to-access-store-state?rq=1) and [redux-form : How to display form values on another component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39036773/redux-form-how-to-display-form-values-on-another-component), but still unable to display the userid in second form component.

Please provide any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

`redux-form` provides [formValueSelector](http://redux-form.com/6.5.0/docs/api/FormValueSelector.md/) that you can use to create a selector that retrieves form values from the redux store. You can sue that in the `mapStateToProps` -function of your `VerifyLoginBodyComponent`.

Example:

```
const selector = formValueSelector('submitValidation')

const mapStateToProps = reducers => {
  const signingInUserId = selector(reducers, 'userid')
  return { signingInUserId }
}
```

This depends of course on the fact that the form values are not cleared from the store until after submitting succeeds.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @jakee. I tried it, but didn't work. Instead of "reducers" in your code, I tried "state" also, but that too didn't work. I had to use the traditional mapDispatchToProps => dispatch an action => reducer and update state, to make it work. 

I am wondering redux-form must have some benefits that will allow me to reduce the coding.

Comment: @jakee- is there a way to make sure, form values are not cleared from the store until submission succeeds ?

Comment: What I meant is that I am fairly sure that the values stay in the store until submission succeeds, unless you unmount the form.