# How to access redux form values in another component

Tags: reactjs, redux-form

I using Redux-Form 7.3.0.  I am trying to get the values of my form in another component. I read the instruction at the [website](https://redux-form.com/7.0.0/docs/api/formvalueselector.md/) of Redux form but didn't work.

```
this is the code of my componenet:

    import React from 'react'
    import { Field, reduxForm } from 'redux-form';
    import { connect } from 'react-redux';
    import { formValueSelector } from 'redux-form';

    class Test extends React.Component {
      render() {
        console.log(this.props);
        return (
          <div>
            test
            {this.props.title}      
          </div>
        );
      }
    }

    const selector = formValueSelector('NewPostForm');

    Test = connect(
      state => ({
        title: selector(state, 'title')
      })
    )(Test)

    export default Test;
```

This is my form component:

import React from 'react';
    import { Field, reduxForm } from 'redux-form';

```
class NewPost extends React.Component {

    renderField(field) {          
        return (
            <div>
                <label>{field.label}</label>
                <input type="text"  {...field.input} />
            </div>
        );
    }

    showResults(values) {

        window.alert(`You submitted:\n\n${JSON.stringify(values, null, 2)}`);
    }

    render() {

        const { pristine, submitting, handleSubmit } = this.props;
        return (
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(this.showResults)} >
                <div>
                    <Field
                        label='Title'
                        name='title'
                        component={this.renderField}
                    />

                    <button type='submit' disabled={submitting}>
                        Submit the from :)
                    </button>                        
                </div>
            </form>
        );
    }
}



export default reduxForm({ form: 'NewPostForm'})(NewPost);
```

but I always get

```
title:undefined
```

I found the same question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39036773/redux-form-how-to-display-form-values-on-another-component) but it did not help me.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your **Test** component has two imports from "redux-form". Please make it just one, like this:

```
import { Field, reduxForm, formValueSelector } from 'redux-form'
```

If your **NewPost** component gets unmounted at any moment, maybe by changing view or something during a navigation, the state of the form gets destroyed. You can avoid such default behavior by adding **destroyOnUnmount** attribute with a **false** value to your reduxForm wrapper:

```
export default reduxForm({
   form: 'NewPostForm',
   destroyOnUnmount: false
})(NewPost)
```

If this doesn't help you, please provide a better context of how you're using your components.

**UPDATE:** I made an example where I define 4 components:

- **NewPost.js**: It's the form connected to the store with redux-form.
- **ShowPost.js**: Shows what was captured (the post) by the form when you hit the submit button. This data is set to the NewPost internal state, and then it's passed as prop.
- **ShowPostFromSelector.js**: Shows what is being captured by the form, this due to the use of the selector *formValueSelector*.
- **App.js**: It's the container of the 3 components above, where the onSubmit function is defined.

**Here it is:** https://codesandbox.io/s/w06kn56wqk

Comment: it didn't help, what info do yo need?

Comment: I did an update to my answer where I leave you an example. Let me know if it helped you.

Comment: @Racsoraul - so whats changed/different in your code?

Comment: @cg Not so sure since I don't know how *farm command2* is using his components or the context that could lead to those problems. The code he posted looks fine, at least each individual component. That's why I posted an example to help him find the potential problem.

Comment: Thanks for your help dear, but it turned out to be an issue with how to go to the new page, i asked another question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49601192/formvalueselector-doesnt-get-the-values-if-i-go-to-the-new-page-via-changing will keep this one up as your answer may help others