# `formValueSelector` doesn't get the values if I go to the new page via changing URL

Tags: reactjs, redux-form, react-router-dom

I am using Redux-Form `7.3.0` and noticed that if go to other pages via changing the URL then if on the new page if I try to get values with `formValueSelector` it doesn't work - will be `undefined`. But if I go to the new page component via `<Link to={'/blabla'}>` (react-router-dom) it will be ok and I get the values. why?

Comment: redux store data is lost when the page is refreshed, you might want to make use of redux-persit to persist the data after reload

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri   so why does it work when I change the page via <Link>?

Comment: Changing via link is the normal flow which is considered a session and data is persisted in redux store via session